# Lotus NotesSQL driver without a local Notes DB

Tags: odbc, lotus-notes

I do not have Lotus Notes installed on my machine. There is a Notes DB that is present on a shared drive that I have access to.
I installed NotesSQL driver 8.5.1 on Win 7 32bit machine. During the installation, the first message was something like "No local Notes DB was found". I continued installation.

After the installation I opened the ODBC manager and the NotesSQL driver was not listed.

The purpose of doing this is to connect to the Notes DB using Excel and export the data in excel files.

To add on there is a file called NSQLE32.exe. When I execute this from command prompt nothing happens. What does this exe do and how is it used?

What am I doing wrong? I want to get the data into excel files.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need Notes or Domino installed for it to work.

See [System requirements](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/products/notesdomino/notessql/).

```
To use Notes data through ODBC, you must have:

  NotesSQL, the Lotus Notes ODBC driver
  An ODBC Driver Manager version 3.5 or later

  One of the following:

    Microsoft Windows 2000 or XP
    Microsoft Windows 2003 Server Standard Edition or Enterprise Edition

  One of the following:

    Lotus Notes Client release 6.0 or later
    Lotus Domino release 6.0 or later
    IBM Lotus Domino Designer release 6.0 or later
    IBM Lotus Domino Off-Line Services release 1.01 or later
```